# Ubuntu 14.04 is too slow

Tags: performance, 14.04

After a successful fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 (from USB flash drive) 
everything is much slower than in previous versions of Ubuntu on the same computer. 
It takes a few seconds to open a window or to close a window
(even a terminal window). When I type a text in the vi editor, the characters appear
on the monitor much slower than I type them. 
When moving a window, the window doesn't follow the mouse.
I never had this problem with previous versions of Ubuntu.

My hardware:
⠀Processor: AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 254  2800MHz
⠀RAM: 4 GB DDR
⠀Hard drive: ST31500341AS  (1500GB)
⠀Graphics: NV43GL [Quadro FX 540]

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: Your symptoms suggest you're using software rendering, which is visually very slow. This could be because you don't have an appropriate driver for your graphics card loaded. Could you tell us whether you installed proprietary NVidia drivers? If not, could you try installing them and seeing if it improves things?

Comment: I agree with @roadmr, this sounds like a graphics problem. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)'s the Ubuntu guide for the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Search the Dash for _Additional Drivers_ and open Additional Drivers to find out if roadmr is right. If there is a [Recommended] graphics driver available, you can install it right there in the Additional Drivers utility.

Comment: Do you want to run **top** on the command line to see if this is not kworker eating up your resources. It's an issue I have been dealing with recently on my two laptops where kworker has gone mad on resources.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem right now... It may not be your case, but I have a DisplayLink adapter. I couldn't make it work in previous Ubuntu versions, but it works now. The problem is that I get the symptoms that you described. I unplugged it, and everything got faster.